# How setup top app bar if I am configuring navigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I am using `NavHost` to declare my navigation bar.
Also I've added a topbar to my screen.

Now I want to link navigation and this topbar. What I should do to have the same result as using [setupActionBarWithNavController](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/ui/NavigationUI#setupActionBarWithNavController(androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity,%20androidx.navigation.NavController))